# Get Json String as command line argument in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, command-line-arguments

I need to pass a json string like below as a command line argument and convert to json object and then to a dataframe.

```
jsonStr<- '{"a": "1 - 2","b": "2 - 3", "c": "111,222"}'
```

I am passing this string to a named argument in command line

```
Rscript test.R --jsonStr="{"a": "1 - 2","b": "2 - 3", "c": "111,222"}"
```

Code to get the argument:

```
option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-b", "--jsonStr"), type="character", default="",
                help="json object", metavar="character"),
  make_option(c("-o", "--output_dir"), type="character", default="",
                help="output_dir", metavar="character")
);
opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser)
if (is.null(opt)){
  print_help(opt_parser)
  stop("At least one argument must be supplied", call.=FALSE)
}

jsonStr <- opt$jsonStr
output_dir <- opt$output_dir

df <- fromJSON(jsonStr) %>% as.data.frame
```

I am getting below error when i run the script from command line:

```
test.R: error: Error in if (j < length(these.flags) & spec[rowmatch, col.has.argument] ==  :
  the condition has length > 1
```

Am i missing something  here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the string argument within single quotes

```
$ Rscript test_Jan17.R --jsonStr='{"a": "1 - 2","b": "2 - 3", "c": "111,222"}'
```

-output

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

      a     b       c
1 1 - 2 2 - 3 111,222
```

-test_Jan17.R

```
library(optparse)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-b", "--jsonStr"), type="character", default="",
              help="json object", metavar="character"),
  make_option(c("-o", "--output_dir"), type="character", default="",
              help="output_dir", metavar="character")
);
opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser)
if (is.null(opt)){
  print_help(opt_parser)
  stop("At least one argument must be supplied", call.=FALSE)
}

jsonStr <- opt$jsonStr
output_dir <- opt$output_dir

df <- fromJSON(jsonStr) %>% as.data.frame
cat(paste(capture.output(df), collapse = "\n"), "\n")
```